# mock newly created instance?

Tags: php, unit-testing, new-operator, phpunit

i have old code which didnt use TDD
now i want to write a test for a function which looks like this

```
function somefunction($someargs){
    // do a few checks on $someargs
    $database = new DB_PG();
    $result = $database->select($query);
    // do some changes on result
    return $result;
}
```

since im not much expirienced with phpunit and testing in general
my question is:
how can i mock DB_PG?
i tried getMock() in my test, but since the function uses "new" to get an instance
my mock object is ignored, which makes sense

so i see only 2 options

1. some features of phpunit i dont know - which is the reason i ask here ^^
2. i have to modify the old code - which i know would be better

so, anyone knows an answer for option 1?

thx all

Comment: How are you configuring this test? Have you read this article on test doubles? Is this a standalone function, or is it a method which is part of a wider class? What do your tests (using getMock) look like?

Comment: * what do you mean by configuring?

* yeah i know this article, but im not sure whats your point here?

* its a standalone function i want to test

and a test it try to get run looks like this
 function test_someFunctionFailed(){
    $pgmock = $this->getMock('DB_PG',array('select'));
    $pgmock->expects($this->any())
           ->method('select')
           ->will($this->returnValue(null))
    $rval = somefunction();

    $this->assertNull($rval);
 }

currently this results in
Fatal error: Call to undefined method DB_PG::select() in ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**OPTION 1**

Can you change the function to work as follows:

```
function someFunc($existingArgs, $db = null)
{
    $db = (is_null($db)) = new DB_PG();
    $result = $db->select($query)

    $return $result;
}
```

This way you can pass in a db instance, this lets you at least test this function, in the future you can refactor things such that someFunc's work is on models, and the db load stuff happens via a dao/repository/factory.

**OPTION 2**

If DB_PG isn't already pulled in via a require/include in the file where this function lives, you can define a dummy class inside your test class

```
class DB_PG
{
    public function select($query)
    {
        //use phpunit's libs to output a mock object, you'll need to use the PHPUnit_Framework_Mock::generate() static method, I think that's the name.
        return $mockResult;
    }
}
```

That way you can control what happens with the result.